# Java "null" value never assigned to my Runnable

Tags: java, null, runnable

So I have this code:

```
    for(Runnable loadTask : mMeshLoadMap.values())
    {
        if(loadTask != null)
        {
            loadTask.run();
            loadTask = null;
        }
    }
```

My problem is the `loadTask = null` statement is never executed, Android Studio says "The value "null" assigned to loadTask is never used"...

Plus when I set a breakpoint at that line the debugger never reaches it.
It can reach `loadTask.run()` but not `loadTask = null`
And I am sure that `loadTask.run()` doesn't block soo long

Comment: No I want a synchronous execution, I don't want to launch threads for my runnables

Comment: Then why are you using the Runnable interface at all? "The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread."

Comment: I think the compiler might actually remove the `loadTask = null;` statement since it doesn't do anything at all. I'm not sure if the JLS allows this but some languages allow the compiler to do pretty much anything as long as the observable effect of the program doesn't change. Since the line with your breakpoint doesn't affect the observable effect in any way, I don't see why the compiler shouldn't drop it.

Comment: @DavidS I am using Runnable as "function" objects. Runnable can be used for anything not only for thread.

Comment: I was just quoting the JavaDoc. Everything in [Runnable documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) describes that the interface is supposed to be used for threads. Of course any class can implement any interface. You can implement [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) if you want, but it doesn't mean it's appropriate.

Comment: Well I don't know if it's appropriate or not but know that even Android API uses runnables to queue synchronized events for example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html (I actually get the idea from there !)

Comment: Oh thanks for sharing, @user2591935. Conventions change! I have learned something today.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It certainly can be assigned, but it is pointless. You'd only be nulling the reference named `loadTask` (which is out of scope outside the block). You cannot update the reference in the array. [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) says (in part)

> The for-each loop hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove. Therefore, the for-each loop is not usable for filtering. Similarly it is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you traverse it.